# How do I generate a chirp that stops at a certain frequency?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

SciPy provides a chirp function to generate a signal that gradually changes frequency. How do I generate one of these signals that stops at a certain frequency and continues with that frequency?

I tried to do this with the following, but the chirp seems to go past the `f1` limit and it creates a choppy transition to the final `f1` resolve

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.io import wavfile

samplerate = 44100
length = 5
chirplength = 3

f0 = 440
f1 = 880

signal = np.arange(chirplength*samplerate)/(chirplength*samplerate)
signal = np.interp(signal, [0, 1], [f0, f1])
signal = np.append(signal, np.repeat(f1, (length-chirplength)*samplerate))
signal = np.sin(signal * 2 * np.pi * np.arange(length*samplerate)/samplerate)
signal = np.float32(signal)
wavfile.write("audio.wav", samplerate, signal)
```

Comment: downvoter and/or person who voted to close, please explain.

Comment: Please read through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: why is this a bad question? I'm just not seeing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to integrate by multiplying with a ramp which obviously won't work.

Try replacing

```
signal = np.sin(signal * 2 * np.pi * np.arange(length*samplerate)/samplerate)
```

with

```
signal = np.sin(signal.cumsum() * 2 * np.pi / samplerate)
```